# How to get animate between elements moving using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

When click `CLICK HERE` div id `photo` will set css to `top: 300px; left: -400px; transform: rotate(-60deg)` how can i add animate into this process ?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function swipeLike() {
    document.getElementById("photo").style.top = "300px";
    document.getElementById("photo").style.left = "-400px";
    document.getElementById("photo").style.transform = "rotate(-60deg)";
}
</script>

<br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div onclick="swipeLike()">
CLICK HERE
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div id="photo">
        MOVING
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can  simply add `transition`:

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function swipeLike() {
        var photo = document.getElementById("photo");
        photo.style.top = "300px";
        photo.style.transition = "0.4s";
        photo.style.left = "-400px";
        photo.style.transform = "rotate(-60deg)";
     }
    </script>

    <br><br><br><br><br><br>

    <div onclick="swipeLike()">
    CLICK HERE
    </div>


    <div class="content">
    <div id="photo">
    MOVING
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which type of animation you want. You can use css3 `transition` property to animate things.

[W3Schools Transition property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to define a `class` with the elements that need to be animated. See below, hope this helps.

```js
function swipeLike() {
  document.getElementById("photo").classList.add("anim");
}
```

```css
#photo {
  transition: all 3s;
}

.anim {
  top: 300px;
  left: -400px;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
```

```html
<div onclick="swipeLike()">
  CLICK HERE
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div id="photo">
    MOVING
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 function swipeLike() {
  document.getElementById("photo").style.top = "300px";
  document.getElementById("photo").style.left = "-400px";
  document.getElementById("photo").style.transform = "rotate(-60deg)";
 }
</script>

<br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div onclick="swipeLike()">
CLICK HERE
</div>


<div class="content">
<div style="transition:all 1s linear;" id="photo">
MOVING
</div>
</div>
```